# Extract String between brackets in a file for all occurrences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, etl

I have a file like:

```
Single-device update
Received at:Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:33 PM
Control unit type:regard
Control unit identifier:rdfdf
Target:dfdfdf
Download start:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:13:40 PM
Download completed:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:13:41 PM
Installation start:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:15:42 PM
Installation completed:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:33:59 PM
Result code OK
DFG Response failed: [0000NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0DNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NN00N00NN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:03 PM
Control unit type:regard
Control unit identifier:fdfd
Target:fdgh
Download start:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 9:43:19 PM
Download completed:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 9:43:19 PM
Installation start:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 9:45:29 PM
Installation completed:
Sun Aug 08 2021, 10:03:45 PM
Result code OK
UDS Response failed: [0000NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0DNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NN00N00NN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
```

I want to be able to search this file and extract all the data within the brackets and produce that as output like:

```
0000NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0DNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NN00N00NN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
0000NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0DNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN0NN00N00NN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

I tried this so far but no luck:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
with open ("results.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
ctr=0
for i in data:
    m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", str(i))
    print(m)
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
import re

with open('results.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        m = re.search(r'.*?\[(.*)].*', line)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
with open ("results.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
ctr=0
for i in data:
    m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", str(i))
    if m:
        # print only the first match
        print(m[0][1:-1])
        print(m.groups[0])

help(m.groups)
"""
Help on built-in function groups:

groups(default=None) method of re.Match instance
    Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1.
    
    default
      Is used for groups that did not participate in the match.
"""
```